# What is equivalent .NET Core command to Aspnet_regiis.exe –ir –enable

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I would like to know how can I port this command to .Net Core 3.1

```
Aspnet_regiis.exe –ir –enable
```

Comment: ASP.NET Core module is there to host .NET Core web apps, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-5.0 so you no longer use a command like `aspnet_regiis`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Aspnet_regiis.exe –ir –enable

The function of this command is to install asp.net.

For .net core we can use the following command to install .net core:

> dotnet-install.ps1 | dotnet-install.sh

For more information about "dotnet-install scripts reference", you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script).